# New object not appearing in Parse data browser

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I want a new `userCategory` object to be created when a user signs up in my iOS app. I figured the best way to do this would be to call a Parse cloud code function once signup is successful that triggers the creation of the object. When I check Parse's databrowser however, the new user is created, but a new `userCategory` associated with the user isn't.

objective-c code:

```
// Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is signed up.
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"userCategoryCreate"
                       withParameters:@{}
                                block:^(NSNumber *ratings, NSError *error) {
                                    if (!error) {
                                        //userCategory created
                                    }
                                }];
}
```

Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("userCategoryCreate", function(request, response) {


  // Simple syntax to create a new subclass of Parse.Object.
var UserCategory = Parse.Object.extend("UserCategory");

// Create a new instance of that class.
var userCategory = new UserCategory();


  response.success("userCategory succesfully created!");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something similar to:

```
// Simple syntax to create a new subclass of Parse.Object.
var UserCategory = Parse.Object.extend("UserCategory");

// Create a new instance of that class.
var userCategory = new UserCategory();

// set necessary fields for the new entry row ( if needed )
userCategory.set("categoryName","categoryFoo1");
...
..
.

// Then save the object

userCategory.save().then(function(savedObj){

 response.success("userCategory succesfully created!");

},function(saveError){

 response.error("Unable to create this object");

});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I see what you're doing here, however when I use this code, I get an error stating `Error: success/error was not called`. Any idea why?

Comment: sorry, i've edit ( save() ,method of Parse.object return a Promise, so i've forgot to call the promise method "then". If you don't want to handle success or error you could use "save().always(function(){})" instead ;)